# Pushing a link to Mobile Device from Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there a way to push a link for more information to the users device if they asked a question to your Action through a voice only google home device?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [multi-surface conversations](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations), where the Action can transfer seamlessly from a Google Home to a phone.

Then you create a New Surface intent and you'll get a notification on your phone to show the content.

```
if (conv.screen) {
  conv.ask(`You're already on a screen device.`);
  conv.ask('What else would you like to try?');
} else if (screenAvailable) {
  const context =
    `Let's move you to a screen device for cards and other visual responses`;
  const notification = 'Try your Action here!';
  const capabilities = ['actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT'];
  conv.ask(new NewSurface({context, notification, capabilities}));
} else {
  conv.ask('It looks like there is no screen device ' +
    'associated with this user.');
  conv.ask('What else would you like to try?');
};
```